# How to stop until thread complete its work

Tags: android, multithreading

just look at the below code:

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {                    
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    rs=net.incCount(emp_id);
                    try{                            
                        JSONArray j_array=new JSONArray(rs);
                        JSONObject j_object=j_array.getJSONObject(0);
                        count_val=j_object.getInt("countget");
                        System.out.println("1 "+count_val);
                        updateStatus=j_object.getString("ins_status");
                        System.out.println("1 "+updateStatus);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("Catch Error "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            if(updateStatus.equals("true")){
                System.out.println("got al "+count_val);
                selectedItem.setCount(count_val);                   
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Not Updated Please Check Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

from this my database get updated but application stops working, thread executes and before thread completion it checks `if(updateStatus.equals("true"))` condition. which gets `null`. so how should i check that means how should i stop until thread complete its work then execute the below code.

Comment: You don't. That would block the main application thread, causing your UI to freeze, and making your thread useless. Do something else to arrange for that code to run on the main application thread after the work in the background thread is done. For example, you could use `AsyncTask` instead of a `Thread`.

Comment: will you give me an example please else any link...

Comment: Don't to that yourself, the easier way is just to use AsyncTask. It lets you define what to execute after the background work is done. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Like CommonsWare said, you can't stop the main thread. A solution is to use an AsyncTask and show a progress dialog while the task is executing. Dismiss the dialog when task finishes.

Answer (score 0):

the method you are using is executing in main thread... if it'll take long than your app will be force close by OS. Try using AsyncTask:

```
public class MyClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    //variables to use across this class 

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Do anything like download, API call etc...

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //in post execute, set your result data. Like set data to textview, edittext, listview etc....

                }
}
```

And Whenever you want to do this task just define like:

```
new MyClass().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot block the main thread (the system will detect that **A**ctivity is **N**ot **R**esponding and will close your app).

First option for you is to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and put the code to be executed *after* the background job in the [`onPostExecute`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) method

Other option is to post a message from your thread to the main thread when your background job is ended:

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //prepare the stuff to send a message to the main thread
                Looper.prepare();
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

                ... //do the backgroud job here
                updateStatus = ... ; //what ever

                if(updateStatus){
                    handler.post(new Runnable(){
                         public void run(){
                             selectedItem.setCount(count_val);
                         }
                    });
                }else{
                    handler.post(new Runnable(){
                         public void run(){
                             Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Not Updated Please Check Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Note that the option 2 is more *low level* and help you to understand how to do it using *classic* java thread... but in the end: the AsyncTask is doing all this annoying boiler plate code for you. (in other words: it's better to use AsyncTask)